# Whats the point of a Bottler?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I don't see the point of a Bottler. All the things it puts into cans\cells other machines can put into cans\cells, usually the default machine that creates the substance. So what gives?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer why did you include the minecraft tag to this question? Vanilla minecraft does not have a bottler machine.

Comment: Site policy is to include the base game when tagging questions about mods.

Comment: Checking the `feed-the-beast` tag, it looks like a particular user has been rolling back my edits to include that tag, so perhaps a reminder of this policy would be in order. Ha.

Comment: @RavenDreamer whats the point of having both a tag labeled MINECRAFT and a tag labeled MINECRAFT-FEED-THE-BEAST on the same question? this screams redundant in so many ways...

Comment: It's the same tagging schema we use for DLC and expansions. Presumably, there are Minecraft-only solutions for some Feed the Beast questions. Likewise, folks who have ignored the Minecraft tag probably do not want Feed the Beast questions sneaking past their filter. Total Conversion Mods (such as DayZ) get their own tag.

Comment: If I recall correctly, machines like the still did not put liquids into cans in previous versions - they had to be sent to a bottler. I will have to dig to verify this though.

Comment: @shanodin Please read the comments here relating to the [minecraft] tag. Thanks!

Comment: @RavenDreamer SevenSidedDie would appreciate your input on my related [meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/tagging-standards-aint-standard-theyre-confusing)

Comment: I think this kind of comment thread discussion is reserved for meta XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious point for the specific existence of the bottler is to be there in case you don't have any other mods installed (the bottler comes from Forestry) that can provide the same functionality.

Also in general this type of machine is useful for situations where you want the machine creating the liquid to pump it into a storage tank and then later on you need to move small amounts of liquid from the tank into cans/cells for a specific use.